# Can't click buttons on webpage unless browser is maximized

Tags: php, html, css

I've never seen this happen before, and I've no idea where to start looking for problems.
I'll start by saying I'm an avid user of this site, among others like it, and I am well aware there are possibly others that have ran into this EXACT issue, but the proper phrasing must've escaped me because I searched all of my resources and couldn't find any information even slightly regarding this problem.

I wanted to make two radio buttons, at the top of my page, to switch between a blog and resume. I've gotten SO CLOSE to what I want, the only issue I'm having is the radio buttons are utterly unresponsive unless my browser is full screen. No hover style change, can't click them, nothing. They might as well be plain text with a background color.

```
<!-- Main Navigation -->
                    <nav class="site-nav">
                        <?php if(is_home() ) {
                        echo '<a class="white-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Blog</button></a>';            
                    } else if(is_page( 'Work History' )) {

                        echo '<div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location=\'#\';">Blog
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary active">
                                    <input type="radio">Resume
                                    </button>
                                </div>';
                        } else {                                         
                        echo '<div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location=\'http://theme-rusers.io\';">Blog
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location=\'',
                                     esc_url(get_permalink( get_page_by_title('Work History'))),
                                     '\';">Resume
                                    </button>
                                </div>';
                    } ?>
```

This is a WordPress theme, I am new to code (within the past year), If I failed to provide correct or enough information please ask me and I will edit this post, and I am using bootstrap.

I have tried to switch to using Buttons instead of a radio selector, and still the same problem occurs.

I really appreciate ANY help on this, if this topic is closed with a simple link to another I apologize in advance, It's been months since I've resorted to asking a question on any forum, as I am usually able to research it on my own, there's plenty of information out there.

Not enough though, apparently ^.^

Full Header.php code: http://www.pastebucket.com/551354

Comment: can you post a link to that page?  sounds like a div is overing your buttons, is that possible?

Comment: You have the radio buttons nested inside of regular buttons... I can't imagine how that wouldn't confuse a browser. Why not just put the radio buttons inside a div?

Comment: i can click that buttons without problem, but the href does not works. 
move`onclick="window.location='https://theme-repo-shaunrd0.c9users.io/work-history';" ` from the input to the button

Comment: They were, the problem persisted and I added the buttons around the radio in effort to find a fix on my own. But, stranger things have happened. I'll retry without the button elements and post if this solves it. Regardless, they arent doing anything i suppose..

Comment: @Nicolo - This confuses me, because if you type that URL into your browser it comes right up. Am i missing something?

Comment: my screen resolution is probably higher than yours, so the div is not hovering in my monitor. try Andy's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons become clickable if I add some `z-index` to their top-level parent container.

```
/* Target the first div which has a sibling from the first row within .container-fluid */

.container-fluid > .row:first-of-type > div:not(:only-child) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I knew I was overlooking something simple. When I was resizing my window the elements would overlap, making the button unclickable. Thanks for your answer, Ill add this for now and clean up later.

Comment: The first thing I do in these situations is open the inspector (Chrome's, in my case) and attempt to hover over the unresponsive element. In your case, I noticed the `h1` "on top" of the `<button>`s and that immediately gave me my answer.